# Past Simple or Present Perfect with "Never"?

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

I have this example in my practice book where I need to use the Past Simple or Present Perfect:

> My grandfather died before I was born. I **have never met** him.

The right answer is "I **never met** him".

Shouldn't we use the Present Perfect with "never"?

Comment: Could you explain why you think we have to use present perfect with "never"?

Comment: Related question, [Can the choice between Present Perfect vs Past Simple be influenced by external events?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301589/can-the-choice-between-present-perfect-vs-past-simple-be-influenced-by-external/301596#301596) and [Present Perfect for the past?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154933/present-perfect-for-the-past).

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "need to place"? Also, regarding 'The right answer is "I never met him"': how is the textbook's question phrased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I've never met him" would imply that you still might, in this life.

Answer (score 1):

The distinguishing feature of perfect constructions in English is that there is some relevance to the present: what the specific relevance is may vary from case to case.

With negatives, the present relevance is nearly always that the circumstances in which the event is possible still hold: you might imagine that it implies the word "yet".

So it would be very odd to use it of seeing somebody who has died.